# How to connect to local Google Cloud Storage (not datastore)

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application written in go and want to access a local google cloud storage - GCS (not datastore). I am not using GAE, I will be using GCE.
How do I set up GCS locally and access it from Go?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)
2. In the console run `gcloud beta auth application-default login`
3. Login with the google account that owns the project
4. In your code, your configuration should be like this:

   cliente, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)

   ```
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   clienteCS = cliente.Bucket(bucketName)
   ```

5)If you haven't created a bucket, I would recomend to creat manually from [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) or with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-gsutil) because you won't be frequently creating buckets
6)Run your code, enjoy

Steps from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) are valid too but is headache